# how to take a report in CSV format in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to take a report in CSV format in php codeigniter

Comment: take('path/to/report')? ;-) What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: Your question needs some detail, and a clearer statement.  Do you want to produce or import CSV?  What are the constraints?

Answer (score 1):

nevermind codeigniter.

[fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) is your friend.

from the php manual:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```